# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function. while using the firebase ,angularfire2 in ionic 3....any help would be mustt appreciated

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

```
{
  "name": "multilingual",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve --sourceMap source-map --iscordovaserve --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/sms": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.18.0",
    "@ionic-native/video-player": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
//here i feel something
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.734.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "com.razorpay.cordova": "git+https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-cordova.git",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-filechooser": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-lib": "3.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "^2.4.0",
    "cordova-sms-plugin": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "1.1.0",
    "firebase": "^7.19.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.10.0",
    "ionic3-star-rating": "^2.1.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "leaflet-ant-path": "^1.3.0",
    "mapmyindia-map-cordova-ionic-beta": "^0.1.6",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "ng2-charts-x": "^2.0.6",
    "npm-git-install": "^0.3.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "2.2.3",
    "razorpay": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.6.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.4.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.18",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.27",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "com.razorpay.cordova": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-sms-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "SENDER_ID": "382684905628",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "11.6.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filechooser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: pls post the code that actually produces the error

Comment: Thanks for the reply...Actually it’s happening when I add the angular fire plugin to the working code.

Comment: sorry but it's hard to understand where exactly the error is happening. is the error thrown in console when serving the app ? or when building for Android or iOS platform ? maybe it's the cordova-plugin-firebase ? It has a lot of issues in github. Need more context to be able to help. You also have angularfire2 in your package.json which has been deprecated in favor of @angular/fire